# Lagrange Multipliers for farthest distance

Tags: number-theory, lagrange-multiplier

I am trying to find the farthest point from the origin to a point on the circle $$(x-2)^2+y^2=1$$ I am not great with the formatting on here but this is what I have so far...

$$f(x,y)=x^2+y^2 $$ $$g(x,y)=(x-2)^2+y^2-1$$
$$\nabla f =\lambda\nabla g$$
$$<2x,2y>=\lambda<2(x-2),2y>$$
(1)$$2x=2\lambda(x-2)$$ (2)$$2y=\lambda2y$$
From (2)$$\lambda=1$$ 
substitute $\lambda$ into (1) and produce 0=-4 which tells me no solution... What did I do wrong???

Comment: Note that $y=0$ is possbile, so that $\lambda$ might not be equal to $1$.

Comment: Hint: Divide (1) by (2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have proved that $\lambda=1$ was impossible.

So from (2):
$$
0 = (\lambda-1)y \implies y = 0;
\\
x - 2 = \pm 1
$$
which gives the maximizer and minimizer.